# Live Stream Video To My Website With RTMP

Tags: wordpress, rtmp, live-streaming, raspberry-pi2

Ok, so I want to create a site like Twitch.tv or Livestream.com where I stream live video to.

**What I have**
1 Raspberry Pi setup as RTMP server
1 Raspberry Pi that I want to set up as encoding server
1 dedicated streaming PC
1 website hosted by Godaddy running WordPress
Needed ports are open on router

**My issue**
I can stream to the Raspberry Pi RTMP server and I can view the stream with a RTMP stream viewer on an outside network, but I can not get the RTMP stream to show up on the site. I have tried Flowplayer and JWPlayer but the stream does not play.

**My question**
Do I need to setup a encoding server? I could use the 2nd Raspberry Pi for this. If that is what I need what do you recommend? Like what software should I use and how do I display that to my site?

Answer (score 0):

"Do I need to setup a encoding server?" 
Not necessarily, RTMP servers will just send out the same stream it gets in. No encoded necessary. If you quality options, you you will need to transcode. A RPIs CPU is way to slow to software transcode, and the hardware encoder is will not provide you with good quality. Also, a raspberry pi (2) only has a 10/100 mbps NIC, so you will be ever limited in how may viewers you can serve. And if you are do this from home, You will need 100 Mpbs+ upload to match.